# How to run commands on remote from a jenkins-worker via ssh?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a declarative pipeline in a Jenkinsfile in order to build and deploy an app.
The deployment is usually done by sshing to the docker host and running:

```bash
cd myDirectory
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml foo
```

I managed to run a single shell command via ssh, but don't know how to run multiple commands after eacht other.

This is what I have now:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'onlyMyHost' }
  stages {
    stage("checkout"){...}

    stage("build"){...}

    stage("deploy") {
      steps {
        sshagent(credentials: ['my-sshKey']){
          sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myUser@foo.bar.com hostname'
          sh ("""
            ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myUser@foo.bar.com 'bash -s' < "cd MyDirectory && docker stack deploy --composefile docker-compose.yml foo"
          """)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This fails. What is a good way of running a script on a remote from my specific jenkins-worker

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `'bash -s'` is added here. Removing that from your SSH command should allow you to execute **docker deploy** remotely.

Moreover, you may run any number of commands in the same line by appending with `;` after each command. For example:

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myUser@foo.bar.com < "cd MyDirectory && docker stack deploy --composefile docker-compose.yml foo ; docker ps"`

Comment: The command you posted does not work, problem seems to be that the character < needs to be escaped with \\